# How to make an InfoPath web form and its web services accessible from the Internet via HTTPS?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I have an InfoPath web form deployed on SharePoint. It has Full Trust, uses web services to obtain data, and some pieces of code to generate filled rows in the form. The web services are custom web services deployed on the same web application on the same site.

I have extended the web application to the Internet Zone with HTTPS access and published it to the Internet. The certificate was generated with the local Certificate Service and hence it is not trusted by default.

When I open the form from the Default Zone (HTTP:80) it works fine. But when I open from the Internet Zone it fails to connect to the web services with an error message complaining about the untrusted certificate.

I would like to configure SharePoint and its Forms Server so that the form connects to the web service in the Default Zone even when the user opens the from from the Internet Zone.

My question is whether it is possible to do this and if so then how?

I have tried to substitute the URL in data connections when the form loads but InfoPath ignores the host part of the URL and issues a request to the same zone as where the user has opened the form.

Comment: Get a certificate from a Certificate Authority like Verisign / Thawte.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Infopath replaces the domain part of the connection URL with according to the current zone.

Since it is a web form it is ok to create connections to another domain. So I created a web site on the local IIS (or it can be another Sharepoint application) with a different domain where I deployed web services.